# Compare between two yocto build which have generated different time while SDK and target are same

Tags: linux-kernel, sdk, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have generated two yocto builds at different times while taking the same SDK and target. So is there any way to verify yocto builds so I could differentiate between them for their timestamp, date and yocto version, etc? And also could get to know whether both bzImages are the same or not.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this to your .bb

```
IMAGE_NAME[vardepsexclude] += "TIME DATE DATETIME"
or 
SDK_NAME[vardepsexclude] += "TIME DATE DATETIME"
```

Then recompile.
For bzImages you can look at checksum

```
md5sum your file
```